# Determining algebraically a point of intersection.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

A student I was tutoring posed the question: "I know how to solve

$$e^{-x} = \ln x$$
graphically, however how do you solve this algebraically?" I have been fiddling around with it for a while and I feel like I'm missing something. I have tried various methods involving series expansions and de Moivres theorem but I feel like I'm on the wrong track. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This equation is not solvable in terms of simple functions (polynomials, root functions, rational functions, exponentials, logs, trig functions, etc.).

Comment: There won't be an exact elementary solution. Did you mean an approximate one?

Comment: @Sharkos: I added the numerical-method tag. The OP just posted it as algebra.

Comment: @dezign How do you know it's not solvable in terms of simple functions? Is there a way to determine that?

Comment: @Bryan Urizar: It's probably not known whether this can be solved in terms of simple functions. See Timothy Y. Chow's [*What Is a Closed-Form Number?*](http://www-math.mit.edu/~tchow/closedform.pdf).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for the paper - I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it could be better to write the equation as
$$e^x\,\log(x)=1$$
By inspection, the solution is $\in (1,2)$.

Expand the lhs as
$$f=e^x\,\log(x)=e \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\,(x-1)^n$$ where the first $a_n$ (which are defined by recursion) are
$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},0,\frac{3}{40},-\frac{7}{144},
  \frac{23}{504},-\frac{29}{720},\frac{629}{17280},-\frac{120287}{
   3628800},\frac{607337}{19958400}\right\}$$

Truncate to some order and perform a power series reversion to obtain
$$x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\,\left(\frac f e\right)^k$$ where the first $b_n$ are
$$\left\{1,1,-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{6},\frac{5}{24},-\frac{37}{60},
   \frac{679}{720},-\frac{1633}{1680},\frac{1921}{4480},\frac{3258
   37}{362880},-\frac{10627109}{3628800},\frac{949279}{190080}\right\}$$

Now, make $f=1$. The decimal representation is $x=\color{red}{1.309}83$

For the fun, using $100$ terms would give
$x=\color{red}{1.309799585804150477669233}70$